# A question on a real sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a real sequence that decays faster than any algebraic speed, that is, $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^pa_n = 0$ for every positive integer $p$. Assume that $$\sum_{n\ge 1}(n+1)^kn^ka_n = 0$$ for every integer $k \ge 0$.

**Question:** Can we conclude that $a_n \equiv 0$?

Comment: It is enough to show that $a_1=0$. You have an infinite linear homogeneous system of equations with infinite number of variables. Try Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Comment: Define $f(x) := \sum_{n \ge 1} a_nx^{n^2+n}$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Then $f(1),f'(1),f''(1),f'''(1),\dots = 0$. Maybe this is helpful.

Comment: @mathworker21 are you sure? The exponents change after the first derivation

Comment: @PietroMajer I'm pretty sure. Just induct

Comment: Oh now I see it, you do $f'(1)=0$; $f''(1)=f''(1)+f'(1)=0$ etc

Comment: did you try Taylor coefficients of $x\exp(1/(x-1))$? If they decay fast, this identity holds since all left derivatives at 1 are equal to 0.

Comment: @Fedor I exactly finished that very computation! It's a counterexample indeed.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's for all $n\ge1$,
 $a_n:=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k\ge0} (-1)^k\frac{k(k+1)\dots(k+n-2)}{k!}$. The sum is bounded by the term with $k\sim \sqrt{n-1}$, and this ensure the wanted decay.

Comment: @PietroMajer well, the 10-th term, for example, tends to infinity. So the maximal term tends to infinity.

Comment: @Pietro Majer  Why don't you post an answer? So I do not need to redo the computation. Thank you

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Because it doesn't work. I was just checking the same idea as Fedor: If we had the OP decay, then we could pass to the limit and get $0=f^{(k)}(1)= \sum n^ka_n$ for all $k$. But we have not, as he's saying. The sum for $a_n$ is bounded by its maximal term, which of larger order than the $(n-1)!$ in the denominator.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Maybe the analogous counterexample works using a non-zero function in a Denjoy-Carleman, non quasi-analtic class,  with support $[-1,1]$

Comment: @Pietro Majer I was thinking the same, but I have not checked

Comment: @PietroMajer the sum may however be very small, but for different reasons. I would try the saddle point method: to change the contour which gives the coefficient so that the function $x^{-n}\exp(-1/(x-1))$ is small on it.

Comment: but in fact if $n^k a_n=o(1)$ for all $k$, shouldn't $\sum_n a_n x^n$ be quasianalitic on $[-1,1]$ by Denjoy-Carleman theorem, so that such a counterexample does not exist? or am I wrong

Comment: for applying Denjoy-Carleman, we should prove some bounds for $\sum_{k\geqslant n} |a_k|{k\choose n}$, right?

Comment: Would this be easy to solve if, instead, we knew that $\sum n^ka_n=0$ for any $k\ge 0$?

Comment: @Seva this is an a priori equivalent question: if $\sum n^ka_n=0$, it certainly satisfies the OP's conditions, but if $a_n$ satisfies OP's conditions, then $(b_n)$ defined by $\sum b_n z^n=\sum a_{n} z^{n^2+n}$ satisfies $\sum n^kb_n=0$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: right; see also Eremenko's answer. I was surprised that the problem is stated in an excessively complicated form and wanted to make sure I get the things right.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions and thanks to @Alexandre for your counter-example. I understand that $\sum n^ka_n = 0$ for every $k \ge 0$ is not enough to conclude $a_n = 0$. I also understand that $\sum (n+1)^kn^k a_n = 0$ implies $\sum n^k a_n =0$. But how does $\sum n^k a_n = 0$ imply $\sum (n+1)^kn^k a_n = 0$ as mentioned in Alexandre's answer?

Comment: I know the reason now. Here is an alternative way to understand this problem. Let $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$. The the assumption means for every $k \ge 0$, $(z\partial_z)^k(\partial_zz)^kf(1)=0.$ One can easily cook up an counter example satisfying this condition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Counterexample. Consider the analytic function in the unit disk
$$f(z)=\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-z}}\right)=a_0+a_1z+\ldots,\quad |z|<1,$$
where the principal branch of the $\sqrt{\;}$ is used.
This is the definition of our sequence $a_n$. Function $f$ extends to a $C^\infty$ function on the unit circle, which evident at every point except $z=1$, and it tends to $0=f(1)$ exponentially
as $z\to 1$. So we have that the sequence $(a_n)$ has your property: $|a_n|$ tends to $0$ faster than any
negative power of $n$ (as Fourier coefficients of a $C^\infty$ function). Function $f$ and all derivatives of $f$ vanish at the point $1$. This implies (by Tauber's theorem)
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots (n-k)a_n=0.$$
for every $k\geq 0$. This easily implies that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ka_n=0$$
for every $k\geq 0$, and then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^k(n+1)^ka_n=0$$
for every $k\geq 0$.

Comment: for $z=-1$ the smoothness is not evident for me

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Replacing $1+z$ by $2+z$ should fix that (or by $1$, for that matter).

Comment: @Christian Remling: thanks for your suggestion.